# Force file save dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jax-rs, cxf

I'm having trouble trying to force a browser to open the file save dialog. I'm using `Content-Disposition` header and attachment, also I'm using `download` attribute of the `<a>` tag. The trouble is that the dialog doesn't appear when there is a default directory for download is chosen in a browser options. Currently I'm working in Chrome.

Here is a snapshot of how I'm trying to make browser show the dialog:

```
var csvUrl = document.createElement('a');
csvUrl.href = url;
csvUrl.download = filename;
csvUrl.click();
```

This is how I'm returning a file from the server (using Apache CXF):

```
return Response.ok(csvData.toString())
               .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename)
               .build();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, you cannot force Chrome to show the dialog. The only thing you can do is show a notice for Chrome users like "If no save dialog box appears, check your downloads folder, your file might already be there!"